# Is it possible to add a type to an existing module in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, reflection, entity-framework-6

I have a situation where I need to dynamically add types to my application.
Basically, what's going on is that we want to use EF6, but still run completely dynamic queries against the database and return a dictionary of key/value pairs. (legacy code, don't ask)

I can achieve this by calling `context.Database.SqlQuery` and passing it a dynamically loaded type, that I create on the fly.

I'm using this method that I found online to do so.

```
private static TypeBuilder CreateTypeBuilder(
    string assemblyName, string moduleName, string typeName)
{

    TypeBuilder typeBuilder = AppDomain.CurrentDomain
        .DefineDynamicAssembly(new AssemblyName(assemblyName), AssemblyBuilderAccess.Run)
        .DefineDynamicModule(moduleName)
        .DefineType(typeName, TypeAttributes.Public);
    typeBuilder.DefineDefaultConstructor(MethodAttributes.Public);
    return typeBuilder;
}
```

Which works great, but every time I add a new type (which may be often) it loads a new dynamic assembly.  Which could result in hundreds of assemblies that are only used once.

I'm able to pull down the dynamic assembly by using the following statement:

```
var loadedAssembly = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().FirstOrDefault(ex => ex.GetName().Name == assemblyName);
```

I'm also able to get the dynamic module using the following:

```
var loadedModule = loadedAssembly.GetModules().FirstOrDefault(ex => ex.ScopeName == moduleName);
```

But that's as far as I get, I can't add any types past that point.

Am I barking up the wrong tree?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key part is this line:

```
.DefineDynamicAssembly(new AssemblyName(assemblyName), AssemblyBuilderAccess.Run)
.DefineDynamicModule(moduleName)
```

That method returns an instance of a dynamic assembly and module. Instead of calling `DefineDynamicAssembly` and `DefineDynamicModule` every time you need a new type, create the dynamic assembly and module once, then call `DefineType` on the module for each type you need. Perhaps something like this:

```
internal static class DyanamicTypeBuilder
{
    private static readonly AssemblyBuilder _assembly;
    private static readonly ModuleBuilder _module;
    private static readonly object _syncBlk = new object();

    static DyanamicTypeBuilder()
    {
        _assembly = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly(new AssemblyName("MyDyanmicAssembly"), AssemblyBuilderAccess.Run);
        _module = _assembly.DefineDynamicModule("MyDynamicModule");
    }

    private static TypeBuilder CreateTypeBuilder(string typeName)
    {
        lock (_syncBlk)
        {
            var typeBuilder = _module.DefineType(typeName, TypeAttributes.Public);
            typeBuilder.DefineDefaultConstructor(MethodAttributes.Public);
            return typeBuilder;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I was also considering that as well.  This is a huge application, and I was wondering the best way to do that.  All these methods are static, so I can't add it as a property on a class.

Comment: @Smeegs I put together an example of something I would try. The lock might be unnecessary or the scope can be reduced, I don't know how thread safe the ModuleBuilder is, so I erred on the side of caution.

Comment: That did the trick, thank you so much.  I'll accept this answer when the timer runs out.

Comment: Is there a reason you put a `lock` around the type builder ?

Comment: `ModuleBuilder` class is indeed not thread safe : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.modulebuilder.aspx